# How to disable optimization in the qooxdoo build process?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

qooxdoo includes some optimizations in its build process which makes it hard to debug "build only" bug. How can I disable the the whole optimizations at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way to achieve this is to set the OPTIMIZE macro to [] in your config.json's top-level "let" section:

```
"let" : {
   ...
   OPTIMIZE : []
}
```