# How can I disable code optimization during build process?

Tags: qooxdoo

I want to disable code optimization during build process to make it easy for duggibg. How can I do it?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to disable optimization in the qooxdoo build process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887622/how-to-disable-optimization-in-the-qooxdoo-build-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the OPTIMIZE macro to [] in your config.json's top-level "let" section as:

> "let" : {
>       ...
>       OPTIMIZE : []
>   }